# Bamboo Branch Plans - Configure different jobs/ tasks for each branch plan

Tags: bamboo

I'm having different project structure in each branch, is it possible configure different jobs/ tasks for each branch in bamboo? If not please suggest me any alternatives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to configure different tasks per branch in Bamboo. I can suggest 2 alternative ways:

1. You can use branch "Variables", use the Script task and have different manipulations based on the branch variable.
2. And if your project structure is really different per branch, I would suggest you to create a new plan for it.